# Protected blank in footnotes between "p." and "number"

Tags: biblatex, citing

I have a general question regarding citing in footnotes and the formatting. 
In some cases the page number is separated from the "p." when there is not enough space and latex forces a wordwrap.
So "author (year), p." are on one line and the page number on the following line.
Would a "protected blank" be a solution to this problem?

Comment: There are hardspaces `~` and thin spaces `\,` that should not break at linebreaks.

Comment: Yes and in fact it's the default with `biblatex`. (Do you really use `biblatex` as your tagging suggests? For more detailed help an MWE would help.)

Comment: I use biblatex / biber. So there is not an option in a package that I can use?

Comment: moewe was right. This is the default with biblatex. I made a mistake - I put a "p." in the squared brackets so that biblatex did not insert the "p." by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write `\cite[12]{sigfridsson}` `biblatex` does all the things for you. It inserts the command `\ppspace` between the automatically inserted "p." and the "12". By default `\ppspace` is `\addnbspace` (a non-breaking space), so you won't get a line break there.

If you use another citation package that does not do this sort of thing automatically for you, consider just using `~`: `\cite[p.~12]{sigfridsson}`.